# Django cannot compare string

Tags: python, django

I get data from 2 table by search key_id in Data table and find key_name in Key table like this.

```
    data=Data.objects.filter(username=username)
    key=Key.objects.filter(key_id__in=data.values_list('key_id'))

    data = {'data':data, 'key':key}
    return render(request,'form.html', data)
```

In html I want to show data key_name which key_name is in table Key . So, I have to use for loop like this code.

```
       {% for data in data %}
          {% for key in key %}
        
           {% if data.key_id == key.key_id %}
              {{ key.key_name }}
           {% endif %}

          {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
```

The output not show anything

If I run this code outside if tag.

```
{{ key.key_id }}
```

It show output like this.

```
001 002 
001 002
```

And if I run this code  outside if tag.

```
{{ data.key_id }}
```

It show output like this.

```
001 001 
002 002
```

Why when I compare it not show anything. How to fix it?

Comment: Do you see that `key.key_id` and `data.key_id` are different?

Comment: It has same data in 2 table. In first loop I think it should compare "001" = "001"

Comment: Shown code cannot format output as two columns, so what you compare with what is unclear. Also `{{ key.key_name }}` != `{{ key.key_id }}` perhaps field `key_name` does not exist or is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommend using different variable names in for loop

```
{% for d in data %}
      {% for k in key %}    
{% if d.key_id == k.key_id %}
      {{ k.key_name }}
```

and I don't see your server sent any values for key_name attribute in

```
 return render(request,'form.html', data)
```

Does key_name exist ?